# Get valid date range. Minimum and maximum

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I need to get the values of a table by validity range. Currently I make a group by the columns of the table and I make a min and max about the year; but this gives me the wrong result for the case of the example. I would need to solve it with sentence sql or with pentaho

Sample data:

```
year validity   Value1  Value2
2004               A     B
2006               A     C
2007               A     B
2008               A     B
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    min(anio), max(anio), value1, value2
FROM tabla
GROUP BY
    value1, value2
```

Wrong result:

```
year min    year max    Value1  Value2
2004        2008           A      B
2006        2006           A      C
```

Expected result:

```
year min    year max    Value1  Value2
2004        2004         A        B
2007        2008         A        B
2006        2006         A        C
```

Please help on this issue.

Comment: Another "Gaps & Islands" problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions to separate the rows into groups according to your logic. Once separated, computing the min and max values is trivial.

For example:

```
select
  min(year_validity) as year_min,
  max(year_validity) as year_max,
  min(value1) as value1,
  min(value2) as value2
from (
  select
    *,
    sum(init) over(order by year_validity) as grp
  from (
    select *,
    case when not ( (value1, value2) = (
      lag(value1) over(order by year_validity),
      lag(value2) over(order by year_validity)
    ) ) then 1 else 0 end as init
    from tabla
  ) x
) y
group by grp
order by value1, value2
```

Result:

```
year_min  year_max  value1  value2
--------  --------  ------  ------
2004      2004      A       B
2007      2008      A       B
2006      2006      A       C
```

For the record, the data script for this case is:

```
create table tabla (
  year_validity int,
  value1 varchar(10),
  value2 varchar(10)
);

insert into tabla (year_validity, value1, value2) values (2004, 'A', 'B');
insert into tabla (year_validity, value1, value2) values (2006, 'A', 'C');
insert into tabla (year_validity, value1, value2) values (2007, 'A', 'B');
insert into tabla (year_validity, value1, value2) values (2008, 'A', 'B');
```